# how can I access a css class from the appended html div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I access a css class created by jquery's append. I tried the following code with a click listener on my class I want to access in the div but the event is not being picked up. Thank you

```
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
  ids.push(item.clientName);
  $("#bookedAds").append("<div class='alert alert-info' role='alert'>"+

    item.clientName+" <button name=' "+item.clientName +
    "' class='btn quickview' id='quickview' adSize ='"+item.adSize +
    "'>Quick View</button></div>"
    ); 

});
//Below is my on click Listener
   $(".quickview").click(function(){

  alert("This is not popping up :(");
});
```

Comment: you should try `$(document).on('click', '.quickview', function(){ // your code });`

Comment: @Sushil Thank you very much I need to buy you a drink :)

Comment: please mark my solution as an answer and upvote it if it helped you. that will be my drink for the day @thwildfire ;)

Comment: Done, enjoy your drink ! ;)

Comment: thank you very much @thwildfire :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92087/discussion-between-thwildfire-and-sushil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger your event on dynamically created elements you need to use event delegation, you can try updating your code like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.quickview', function(){ 
    alert("This is popping up :)");
});
```